# jquery not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have some very simple code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#module_body_News').height(0);
});
```

This works fine in Firefox but not in IE.

Why?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using [`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#module_body_News').css('height', 0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to simply hide it(),

```
  $('#module_body_News').hide();
```